# Assigning Values to Subsets of Subsets

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I have four lists of a custom `Trial` object, which contains data about individual trials in an experiment.  The lists are `MC_inducer_con`, `MC_inducer_diamond_con`, `MC_inducer_orientation_con`, and `MC_inducer_color_con` from here on referred to as `con`, `diamond`, `orientation`, and `color` respectively.  `color` is a subset of `orientation` is a subset of `diamond` is a subset of `con`.  Depending on whether or not a given `Trial` object is in each of these lists determines what values are assigned to it.  My problem is twofold, depending on the method I use to implement these conditions on each trial.

If I evaluate each subset with a set of nested if statements:

```
if self.trial in self.MC_inducer_diamond_con:
    self.trial.attr["target_shape"] = TARGET_SHAPES[rand_shape]

    if self.trial in self.MC_inducer_orientation_con:
        self.trial.attr["target_orientation"] = ORIENTATIONS[rand_orientation]
                            
        if self.trial in self.MC_inducer_color_con:
            self.trial.attr["target_color"] = COLORS[rand_color]
        else:
            self.trial.attr["target_color"] = COLORS[1 if rand_color == 0 else 0]
    else:
        self.trial.attr["target_orientation"] = ORIENTATIONS[1 if rand_orientation == 0 else 0]
else:
    self.trial.attr["target_shape"] = TARGET_SHAPES[1 if rand_shape == 0 else 0]
```

I run into a problem where if a trial is in a superset but not a subset (for example if in `diamond` but not `orientation`, `color` or `con`) then the rest of the code is not evaluated and the remaining fields in the `Trial` objects are left empty.  What the code *should* do is assign each trial a different value if not in a given set.

If instead I structure the code like this:

```
if self.trial in self.MC_inducer_diamond_con:
    self.trial.attr["target_shape"] = TARGET_SHAPES[rand_shape]
elif self.trial in self.MC_inducer_diamond_con and self.trial in self.MC_inducer_orientation_con:
    self.trial.attr["target_shape"] = TARGET_SHAPES[rand_shape]
    self.trial.attr["target_orientation"] = ORIENTATIONS[rand_orientation]
elif self.trial in self.MC_inducer_diamond_con and self.trial in self.MC_inducer_orientation_con and self.trial in self.MC_inducer_color_con:
    self.trial.attr["target_shape"] = TARGET_SHAPES[rand_shape]
    self.trial.attr["target_orientation"] = ORIENTATIONS[rand_orientation]
    self.trial.attr["target_color"] = COLORS[rand_color]
```

I run into a separate issue where I can only have one `else` statement to encapsulate a multitude of other possibilities (essentially, each combination of being/not being in each set).

Can anyone point me in the right direction for correctly evaluating these possibilities?  Maybe taking advantage of class inheritances?  I can be more specific about the requirements if need be, but I'm hoping a solution can be found with even this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a separate if-else for each? As far as I understand from your examples, one does not affect the other one. So, something like this should work:

```
if self.trial in self.MC_inducer_diamond_con:
    self.trial.attr["target_shape"] = TARGET_SHAPES[rand_shape]
else:
    self.trial.attr["target_shape"] = TARGET_SHAPES[1 if rand_shape == 0 else 0]

if self.trial in self.MC_inducer_orientation_con:
    self.trial.attr["target_orientation"] = ORIENTATIONS[rand_orientation]
else:
    self.trial.attr["target_orientation"] = ORIENTATIONS[1 if rand_orientation == 0 else 0]
                            
if self.trial in self.MC_inducer_color_con:
    self.trial.attr["target_color"] = COLORS[rand_color]
else:
    self.trial.attr["target_color"] = COLORS[1 if rand_color == 0 else 0]
```

If this does not help, please share the data structure by abstracting the details of your case. For example, no need to use `self` in the examples, sharing the structure of the `Trial` object would be helpful, namings can be more simple, etc. So, we can see your need more easily.

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem for me.  Not sure why I didn't think to do that.  Maybe I just got caught in them being subsets that I assumed the `if` structure would need to be "subsetted"

Comment: yw, I am happy that it works, sometimes we just need somebody else's eyes :)